# Image distorted when widget size differs from dimensions of stored image

Tags: python, image, widget, kivy

I have a square button like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class MyTestApplication(App):
    def build(self):
        b = Button(size_hint=(None, None), height=200, width=200,
                   background_normal='my_icon.png')

        return b

MyTestApplication().run()
```

The image I set as a button background is distorted when I use a button size that differs from the stored image.

The image `my_icon.png` is this:
[image]

When I use `height=100` and `width=100` (those are the actual dimensions of
`my_icon.png`) it looks as expected.

However, when I use smaller or greater values I get the following:
[image]

and

[image]

**Question:**
What causes this distortion and how can I fix it?

Comment: @yoavglazner The 2 last images in the post are screenshots; the first is the actual image, 2nd and 3rd are the distorted images. (I had them included all along. If anything about the question is not clear, let me know so that I can edit it. Although the accepted answer solved my problem)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The disortion is caused by `border` attribute, and can be fixed by setting it to `border=(0, 0, 0, 0)`.
More info here: 
https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html#kivy.uix.button.Button.border